Multilingual menu links are displayed on all languages no matter the settings
Menu itself has no language, only menu links have language. This means that only links in selected language for current page should be shown. This is how it has worked since Drupal 7. But for some reason I cannot get the same behaviour in Drupal 11.
This behaviour doesn't change whether menu language is set to "not specified" or "not applicable".
Block language settings have no influence as well. All menu links are shown whether I select all languages, no language or one language. If I place the same menu in three blocks with different languages each, I get three full menus no matter what language the content is in.
Something isn't working it seems.
Exporting configuration in drush shows that block language has always been set to default langauge (which isn't true) but if I change that and import configuration, nothing changes.

How were these menu links created, and what do they link to? What are the language fallback settings at the admin config page?  If the links are to nodes that do not have translations for each language, the fallback settings may be causing them to always be displayed.

What do you mean by language fallback? The default language? I don't see how it matters, language selection for content works as it should. Language is detected by path prefix.
This problem exists even if I create a new menu for testing with only three links to the front page, each link set in different language. Drupal should show me only the link in a language for current page but it displays all three no matter what. It does show front page content in correct language if I use correct path prefix.

When you export the config, the main folder contains menus and blocks in the original language and separate folders store the translated config objects for each language. However, the languages in these objects only affect the translatable strings.
For the menu object, these are the label and the description:
/config/sync/system.menu.main.yml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: main
label: 'Main navigation'
description: 'Site section links'
locked: true

/config/sync/language/fr/system.menu.main.yml
label: 'Navigation principale'
description: 'Liens de section du site'

Most menu links are defined as content. Try for example
www.example.com/admin/structure/menu/item/1/edit/translations
to translate the first menu link of your site. If you have translations for each language they should display according to the language negotiation.
If you are not able to translate custom menu links, you need to enable it at
www.example.com/admin/config/regional/content-language

I don't translate the menu. Most links in different languages are unique.
This problem is not specific for one certain menu as well. I created a test menu with three links to front page, each set to different language. Drupal should show me only link in language selected for current page but it doesn't, all three links are shown at all times.

I explained langcode: en in the menu, this is only for the two translatable strings. In the question, you tried to use it for other things. To translate a menu link you need to enable the feature on the last admin page mentioned and then use the translation tab on the menu link edit page or the integrated menu option on the node edit page.

Again, I don't translate neither menu nor menu links. I have built websites this way on drupal 7, 8, 9 and 10 and never had such problem before. Menu language is set to be not specified, menu links have their individual languages.
I have enabled config_translation, content_translation and menu_link_content modules and set menus translatable, Without that I wouldn't even have an option to set menu link languages.
However, I just tried to follow your suggestion and followed translation link on menu settings page and got access denied error. I am user 1 so there seems to be something wrong.

As said setting the menu language or block language to not specified has no effect. I've answered to clear this up (this is the only content of your question). I'm not aware of any changes between Drupal 8/9/10/11. Since D8 there is an open issue for the situation described in your last comments. You could try the patch or one of the mentioned workarounds. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2466553
